# Calling PHP Titles inside Javascript Markup

Tags: php, shortcode, javascript, formatting, html

I have a video gallery, and all the titles are generated by `php`. They are coming from my Wordpress media library's attachment titles.

The lightbox for these videos, however, is customized in javascript. How can I put the `php` titles inside the `iframe` `markup`?

PHP - need to use `$attachment_data['title']`:

```
     <?php 
       $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'attachment','category_name' => 'video')); 
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>

     <?php $attachment_data = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $attachment->ID );
          echo'<div class="title"><h2>'.$attachment_data['title'].'</h2></div>';?>
             <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('.video').Lightbox({
      type: 'iframe'

      iframe: {
         markup: '<div class="lightbox_container">'+
                    '<iframe class="iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
                    '<div class="title"> PHP GOES HERE </div>'+
                  '</div>',
callbacks: {
    markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
     values.title = item.el.attr('title');
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer included a solution for this, discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612258/title-for-iframe-video-in-magnific-popup

First I needed to include the title in my `php`:

```
echo'<figure><a class="video" title="'.$attachment_data['title'].'" href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'credit_url', true).'">';
```

And then, I needed the callback:

```
callbacks: {
    markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
     values.title = item.el.attr('title');
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First, don't echo your php, but assemble everything in a string, let's say `$titlestring`.

Next, make this string available for access by the javascript (the slug is the one you used to register the script):

```
$params = array (
    'titlestring'   =>  $titlestring,
    );
wp_localize_script ('your-script-slug', 'IframeTitle', $params);
```

Finally, access the variable in the script:

```
'<div class="title">' + IframeTitle.titlestring + '</div>' +
```

Comment: You should use DOM element construction, joining HTML together in strings is a security hazard

Comment: Or you could assemble the whole string in PHP, so you don't need to concatenate in the script

Comment: So, would it be best for me to use a function inside wordpress' functions.php?

Comment: In this case, yes. It would be even beter if you don't load your lightbox in an iframe but in an overlay div.